# How to call parent functions from inner nested function?

Tags: javascript

I have a simple jQuery `ready` event that initializes a view by calling the a function in the `setupView` object.

The question I have is, what is appropriate way to call the function `setSomethingImportant` from the `init` function as shown below?

Since the call is made from a different execution context than the `init` function, `this.setSomethingImportant()` does not work. However it works if I use `setupView.setSomethingImportant()`. The problem I have with this is that if the var name (`setupView`) changes, I will have to change the body of the code as well.

```
   (function() {        
        $(document).ready(function() {              
            setupView.init();               
        });     
         var setupView = {          
            currentState : "CT",            
            init : function () {
               $("#externalProtocol").change( function () {
                    console.log("Changed =" + $(this).val());
                    setSomethingImportant(); 
                               // Question ? how to call a method in the setupView object   
                });         
             },         
             setSomethingImportant : function () {
                 this.currentState="TC";    
                 console.log("Something has changed :" + this.currentState );
             }      
         }  
 }(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Store `this` into a variable:

```
var setupView = {
    currentState: "CT",
    init: function() {
        // Keep a reference to 'this'
        var self = this;
        $("#externalProtocol").change(function() {
            console.log("Changed =" + $(this).val());

            // Use the old 'this'
            self.setSomethingImportant();
        });
    },
    setSomethingImportant: function() {
        this.currentState = "TC";
        console.log("Something has changed :" + this.currentState);
    }
};
```

See the [*Working demo*](http://jsfiddle.net/A5K5g/).

Comment: Thanks @Florent. To be honest I have been using the approach you suggested. But I was not sure if storing "this" in a variable is a best practice.

Comment: Sometimes you don't have the choice. The less you use this _trick_, the cleaner your code will be.

Answer (score 1):

Just declare the function separately and then call like so:

```
function setSomethingImportant(context) {
    context.currentState="TC";    
    console.log("Something has changed :" + context.currentState );
};

(function() {        
        $(document).ready(function() {              
            setupView.init();               
        });     
         var setupView = {          
            currentState : "CT",            
            init : function () {
               $("#externalProtocol").change( function () {
                    console.log("Changed =" + $(this).val());
                    setSomethingImportant(this); 
                               // Question ? how to call a method in the setupView object   
                });         
             },         
             setSomethingImportant : function () {
                 setSomethingImportant(this);
             }      
         }  
}(jQuery);
```

Comment: You're still passing the wrong context from within the `change` handler.

Answer (score 1):

Please note that I changed my original solution.  I am now passing data to the event handler using [even.data](http://api.jquery.com/event.data/).

```
(function() {        
    $(document).ready(function() {              
        setupView.init();               
    });     
    var setupView = {          
        currentState : "CT",            
        init : function () {
            $("#externalProtocol").change({ _this: this }, function (event) {
                console.log("Changed =" + $(this).val());
                event.data._this.setSomethingImportant(); 
            });         
        },         
        setSomethingImportant : function () {
            this.currentState="TC";    
            console.log("Something has changed :" + this.currentState );
        }      
    }  
 }(jQuery);
```